# replicate old file server machine from 2003sp2 to 2012r2

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012-r2, dfs

I just read this great post:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2014/11/05/migrating-file-server-from-windows-server-2003-to-windows-server-2012-r2.aspx

I was wondering if i could achieve a similar result with windows server 2003sp2 and a virtual machine with windows server 2012R2 using DFS.

I thought that i might enable dfs on the old xxx.domain1.yyy machine

and configure it on the new kkk.domain2.zzz machine. 
Then activate dfs replication.

Has anyone attempted this or is it nonsense?

I think I found the answer. 
I could replicate 2003r2 (and not 2003) using dfs to 2008r2 but not to 2012r2.
But it would be possible to use DFS and replicate an old windows server 2008R2 to a new windows server 2012R2.

Comment: Windows 2003 uses FRS replication instead of DFSR replication that most Windows Server 2012/2012 R2 are making use of. Windows Server 2008 R2 actually works with both being an intermediary on Microsoft's transition from legacy FRS to the most recent DFSR. Not sure what you want to do but you can replicate from 2003 to 2008 R2 and then from 2008 R2 to 2012/2012 R2. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you. essentially i would like to provide availability to the shares of a machine that is going to be dismissed using a newer one.

Comment: It sounds you firstly have to copy over the files from the old server shares to the new server shares and then implement DFSR (and/or DFSN) on two servers to achieve high availability for your shares. I would suggest you should use a copy tool like Robocopy and then on latest server OS to use what DFS has to offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do it was to perform a robocopy of the file server into a newer one.
I solved my problems just following the steps in the original post that triggered the question
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2014/11/05/migrating-file-servers-from-windows-server-2003-to-windows-server-2012-r2/
The distributed file system approach didn't work for me.

Comment: This is a questions and answers site, not a link collection. Please include relevant content in your answer, not just a link to where the content may be as external links can go dead / be removed at any time. The link is nice to have in addition for reference or for further information. For more tips, see [about] and [answer].